# Office Addin: Excel Depth First Search

Tags: excel, typescript, office-addins

**tl;dr** I am having problems with executing a recursive function on an Excel sheet. I will provide as much detail to my problem below as possible but I would appreciate a simple, working async recursive example unrelated to the specific domain/problem I am trying to solve as that might be easier

**Problem Context**

I am trying to build an add in (task pane) in order to linearize multi-variable analysis (i.e. what if analysis) and constraint solving in spread sheets. My hypothesis is that the inherently two dimensional grid of spreadsheets doesn't scale well as the number of variables grow. I would like to try to surface this functionality through an integrated query language.

Because Excel doesn't allow me to tap into it's interpreter, I need to copy the chain of formulas to cells that are out of view, run my computations there and then copy the results to where the user wants them.

This requires me to recursively explore the formula in question and copy all the nested formulas that may be effected by the variables in question.

For example if I have the following structure.

```
A7 -> IF(A5>0, A4, A3)
A5 -> A1 + A2
A4 -> A1 + 10
A3 -> A2 + 10
A1 -> 10 
A2 -> 20
```

I start at the target formula and explore the formulas and copy them to a new location. As I copy them, I build a new environment that tell me where to look. i.e.

```
IF(A5>0, A4, A3) 
  -- A5
     -- A1 
     -- A2 
   copy(A5, copyTo = B5, env(A5 -> B5)) 
  -- A4 
     -- A1
   copy(A4, copyTo = B4, env(A5 -> B5, A4 -> B4))  
  -- A3 
     -- A2 
   copy(A3, copyTo = B3, env(A5-> B5, A4-> B4))
new_formula = replaceCells(A7, env) // this will return  IF(B5>0, B4, B3)
copy(A7, copyTo=B7, env)
```

So tl;dr is it's depth first search + environment accumulation, which is normally very simple to do

**Actual Problem**

However I am having a difficult time wrapping my head around Officejs's concurrency model. Because each recursive call gets executed asynchronously, mutating the environment becomes problematic (while there aren't any race conditions here, the bindings from each depth needs to be present at the time of execution of the one above to allow for correct rewriting

When my first call to this function returns unfortunately a lot of the bindings are missing. I tried solving this issue with both `async/await` and the `Promise` API to no result. What is the proper way of going about this? (I am 100% sure this is a concurrency issue. Not only it makes sense but this code works in Google AppScript, where the concurrency model is much more limited).

P.S. You might ask, "if you want this to execute sequentially, why is it async?" -> It's because I need to load in the formulas in the target cell which requires me to sync the context.

P.S. 2: I have also read [Avoid using the context.sync method in loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/correlated-objects-pattern) but can't seem to find a way around it.

```
async function exploreAndCopy(
    context: Excel.RequestContext, 
    currentWorksheet : Excel.Worksheet, 
    source: string,
    target : string,
    row : string,
    column : number,
    env: Map<string, string>) {

  let rx = currentWorksheet.getRange(target);
  rx.load()
  await context.sync();
  let cellFormulas = rx.formulas;

  if (cellFormulas.length > 0){
    var f : string = cellFormulas[0][0]
    var newFormula = f.replace(source, "A29")
    
    //Get the referenced cells 
    let cells : string[] = newFormula.split(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/)
    cells = cells.filter(s => s.match(/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])/));

    //remove dublicates  
    cells = cells.filter((item, index) => cells.indexOf(item) === index);


    for(var c of cells){

        // ATTEMP #1
        await exploreAndCopy(context, currentWorksheet, source, c, row, column + 1 + cells.indexOf(c), env)

       // ATTEMPT #2 
       exploreAndCopy(context, currentWorksheet, source, c, row, column + 1 + cells.indexOf(c), env).then( p => 
        env.forEach((value: string, key: string) => {
          newFormula = newFormula.replace(key, value)
        })
      ); // will mutate the env


      // Also tried Promises.all 
      await context.sync();
    }
  }
  await context.sync();

  //replace everything in the map 
  var finalFormula = newFormula
  env.forEach((value: string, key: string) => {
      finalFormula = finalFormula.replace(key, value);

  });
  
  //set env
  
  env.set(target, row + column)
  //override    
  var targetCell = currentWorksheet.getRange(row + column)
  targetCell.formulas = [[finalFormula]]
}
```

Appreciate any recommendations you might have

Comment: This may be easier to do using the COM API which has an EVALUATE method for executing formula strings and can trace precedents and is synchronous. (I have been asking for EVALUATE in Office-JS for years). You could use VBA (XLAM addin) or a .NET language via COM-Interop using VSTO or XLDNA. With VBA your UI would be  a Userform (VBA cannot access Task Panes).

Comment: @CharlesWilliams thank you for the recommendation. COM seems to require a visual studio distribution with a special workload installed which I can't seem to locate. Would you be able to point me in the right direction by any chance?

Comment: Google 'Install VSTO' or look at Excel DNA